# Scrollable Custom Menu with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, menu, google-sheets

I searched but couldn't find an answer for this.

I'm populating a custom menu on Google Sheets with an array. This works for me, but as the size of the menu grows, users would be unable to select options at the bottom due to sheer size. Is there a way to make this menu scrollable?

Answer (score 0):

Since [Class ScrollPanel](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/scroll-panel) was already deprecated as of December 11, 2014, your given option is to use the HTML service to create user interfaces as also recommended in [UI Style Guide for Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/style).

You can use the add-ons CSS package in your HTML service pages to control selection of your menus. As stated in [Select menus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/style#select_menus),

> If the list grows too long, consider using a different control. For example, you might display a scrollable list to give the menu more space and make it easier to navigate.